# chaining array with angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I send an array to a function that will use all of the instance of an array? 
I did it like this: (title is array which contain many titles of movies) I need to get information for every title:

```
    export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {}
    results: any = [];
    title: string[] =["Jurassic World","Titanic"];
    apiUrl = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=89089a31&t=';
    getMovies(title) {
    this._httpClient.get(this.apiUrl+ this.title)
   .subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.results = data.Search;
    console.log(this.results);
  })}
ngOnInit() {
this.getMovies(this.title);  } 
}
```

Comment: are you just trying to have a function that can read the contents of the title[] array ?

Comment: @Flightdoc5242 yes, the gunction "getMovies" not working with "title" in the way I did it

Comment: i've reproduced your code below with some minor edits in an answer

Answer (score -1):

I was able to run it and get results like this:

[image: appcomponent.ts]

according to the docs on OMD, the API call is only a singular search, it doesn't like multiple search query's, looks like you can only pass one string at a time.

[image: results]

in your code above you also are doing this:

```
.subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.results = data.Search;
    console.log(this.results);
```

calling .Search on the data results? this was generating an error on typescript, as you can only call into known properties.

if you want to pass in multiple searches, you need to iterate over the array and pass in the iterator as the new item,  this may not be the cleanest way, as i wrote it on the fly, but it get's you what you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, right, what I need to do is to fetch the data from the api, to search for every title in the array - to give the search result from the api. so for me it worked on on given title `ngOnInit() {
 this.getMovies("Titanic"); }` it gives all the results for the movie. but how can I do it for array of titles?

Comment: since you can only pass one query at a time to the OMDB API, i would iterate over the array and pass in subsequent requests swapping out the title for each new array item,  then store each results into a new array with .push()

Comment: i've edited my answer above to show a working example

Comment: I didn't notice I did it sorry, probably clicked by mistake

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I'll try it. wonder about what you said, can I call 1 api request to get the movies name and to iterate with the api above for every iterate of the first one? to avoid the issue with the array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185990/discussion-between-kate-beck-and-flightdoc5242).

Comment: Placing code as images is frowned upon. Could you maybe adapt your answer to include code as text?